# How can I retrieve images from local folder using XML to my app

Tags: iphone, xml, image

What I did is creating a local folder named images and retrieving the images from the folder.

For that I am writing code `UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"`. But I need to get images using XML file dynamically.

How can I do this? Please post some code or link.

Comment: please replay any one  how can i get images from xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use an XML parsing framework that reads your XML file and creates an NSSet or something similar filled with your images.

An alternative could be using JSON instead of XML (faster, less overhead). I made some good experiences with [json-framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/).

Comment: how to use json pls post some link or example on that

Comment: Without knowing, I just clicked through the pages of the link I posted in my answer and found that Wiki of the json-framework: http://github.com/stig/json-framework/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions